# MongoDB: $filter multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have an collection like:

```
{
   _id: 0,
   items: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2, price: 10 },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 240 }
   ],
   T: [
     { item_id: 2993, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 90103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 398, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
    ]
}
{
   _id: 1,
   items: [
     { item_id: 23, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 38, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
   ],
   T: [
     { item_id: 23, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 38, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
     ]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    items: [
       { item_id: 4, quantity: 1, price: 23 }
    ],
   T: [
     { item_id: 203, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 003, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 398, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
     ]
}
```

I want to return a all the items in the items array with a price >= 100. That is done with the following:

```
   $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
```

How can I expand this expression to `$filter` on the `items` array and the `T` array all elements that have a price >= 100?

Comment: Hi JohnnyHK, i want to basically filter on both the T and items array with the same condition. So I expect the output to be all the documents with the T and items array only containing elements with a price >= 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include both the `items` and `T` fields in the same `$project`, each with its own `$filter`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
        },
        T: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$T",
               as: "t",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$t.price", 100 ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```